# How to use Xammp or apache with Unity

Tags: mysql, apache, unity-game-engine, xampp

I m not very good with SQL and database in general.

I created a login database with its login menu. I use XAMMP ( apache and MySQL) to connect to a server through a .php file.

The thing is, when i run my project, i cant connect to my database if apache is not running (although mySQL is but that seems unrelevant).

I was wondering how to i make apache run automaticaly with my project or enable my project to connect to my databse without the need to connect to apache?

Or am i missing something essential?

PS: I have a xammp folder(with all the xammp related stuff), a login.php file inside it which is not inside my project folder

Comment: If you're trying to embed a database with your application, there are simpler standalone solutions. If you're trying to connect to a remote server, that server will have to be running in order to respond.

Comment: so i suppose my apache server was created on my desktop. Do run my project on my laptop i would need it to be running (the server) on my desktop?